# Variable for Altering String Output in `printf()` - C Language

Tags: c, string, printf

In C, as I understand so far, this would be correct:

```
printf("%10s\n", "This is C");
```

would return:

```
" This is C!"
```

(with the intentional space prior to the string; no quotations).

My question is can you replace the `10` specifying the length of the print using a variable? If so, how?

Comment: Detail: `10` does not specify the length of the print.  It specifies the _minimum_ length.  Unclear where the output `!` came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how:

```
printf("%*s\n", 10, "This is C");
```

The format changed from `%10s` to `%*s`. The `printf()` now would expect among the argument, before the string, an `int` with the width to pad the string to (the `10` in the example above; obviously could be a variable too).

To tell the `printf()` to pad the output to the left (instead of the default right) use the `-`: `%-*s`. (The output would change from `" This is C"` to `"This is C "`.)

To tell the `printf()` to take only few first bytes from the string, or if the string is not null-terminated, you can add `.*` to the format at the same place as the precision for floating point types. The `printf()` would print up to that number of characters, stopping at the first null character. Example:

```
int width = 10;
int chars = 4;
printf( "%-*.*s", width, chars, "This is C" );
```

would produce output `"This      "`.

Comment: Could you please add some context to your code?

Comment: @ppperry, updated answer.